# Tell iTunes to open a .m3u playlist file

Tags: bash, applescript, itunes

I'm trying to open a .m3u playlist file in iTune using applescript. I can open an iTune playlist file using:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes"
    play playlist "my playlist"
end tell
```

How can I pass a full path that points to a .m3u file present in any location? Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes"
    play playlist "/path/to/folder/file.m3u"
end tell
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe iTunes knows about m3u playlists... so I doubt you can play it as is. Can you use the playlist by hand e.g. not using applescript? I doubt it. What you would need to do is read the contents of the playlist as text into an applescript and then convert the path to the music into an iTunes playlist... then play that.

Comment: By the way, other programs can use m3u playlists. I think VLC can so you might have an easier time using that to play the music.

Comment: Clicking an .m3u file opens it in iTunes, which creates on-the-fly a "iTune playlist". If I can do it using terminal, whatever the command, I'd be happy.

Comment: OK, glad to hear I was wrong. I'll post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you point out in the comments to your question that you can open an m3u playlist in iTunes and it creates an iTunes playlist, then my suggestion would be to do it that way. First issue the "open" command and after the playlist is created in iTunes then issue the "play playlist" command.

Assuming the name of the playlist created in iTunes is the file name of the m3u file then this might work. Note also that applescript uses file specifiers, not posix paths to a file, so we convert your posix path to a file specifier by using the "POSIX file" command.

I haven't tried this but it's my best guess as to what might work. Good luck.

```
set posixPath to "/path/to/folder/fileName.m3u"
set fileSpecifier to POSIX file posixPath
tell application "iTunes"
    open fileSpecifier
    delay 1 -- delay however many seconds needed to allow the playlist to be created
    play playlist "fileName"
end tell
```

***EDIT***: The error could come from when iTunes converts your m3u file into an iTunes playlist. There might be something in the m3u file causing the error. I don't know what to suggest for that.

However, the error might also come from the POSIX file command. That's touchy sometimes. So one thing you might try to address that possibility is to coerce that command to text and then create the specifier using the word "file" before the string path. So try this. If the error is from the POSIX file command then this should fix it.

```
set posixPath to "/path/to/folder/fileName.m3u"
set fileSpecifier to (POSIX file posixPath) as text
tell application "iTunes"
    open file fileSpecifier
    delay 1 -- delay however many seconds needed to allow the playlist to be created
    play playlist "fileName"
end tell
```

Comment: Great it works! Though it does works I get an error message in the terminal: "./myscript.sh:252:274: execution error: iTunes got an error: Can’t make some data into the expected type. (-1700)". Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm glad you have something working. Look in the EDIT section at the bottom of my post for a possible fix to your error.

Comment: It has no effect :s Anyway it works and I may find the solution later after shedding some thought on it. Thanks!

Comment: One other thought... since the code works and then errors the error must come at the end. The Terminal usually prints out the last action of the applescript as text. The last action of this code is "play playlist" so maybe that action can't be coerced to text thus causing an error. So a solution would be to return some text as the last line of code. Try adding something like return "success!" after the "end tell" line. It might work!

Answer (score 0):

you want to use command line parameter?

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "iTunes"
    play playlist "$1/file.m3u"
end tell
```

Where `$1` is your command line parameter (the first one)

Comment: No parameter, only the full path in the script :)